# Modelling many relations on powerbi desktop

Tags: model, powerbi, dax, data-modeling

I have bellow tables on PowerBI desktop, I want to relate the Account table to the event table without passing by the Opportunity table (the account in the event isn't the same as in the opportunity). The Account is very large so I don't want to duplicate it.
I would like also to relate the case table to the Event table, the relation is 1:Case -> n: Event.
What is the best way to model that on powerbi desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Junk Dimension**

If Opportunity and Event table has few attributes and has few values, then create a single table and include details of both these tables.

[image]